# spf and dkim records in the same dns zone file

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, dkim

I am trying to set up a mail server which will sign outgoing messages with a dkim signature.  Part of that process is to set up a dns record for my senders domain with the public key of the key used to sign the message.

I already have a valid spf key in the txt record.

how do I format the txt record in the dns which contains both sets of information?

Answer (score 2):

### You don't!

SPF and DKIM will not share the same FQDN, as the DKIM key owner name is in the form:

```
[selector]._domainkey.yourdomain.com
```

Where SPF will always have the same owner name as the sending domain (ie. `yourdomain.com`)

Comment: And you can add multiple txt records in any case.

Comment: I don't really understand what that means - and your answer sort of assumes I do (as does every other article on the internet that I can find).  There is a third party who provides the nameserver for mydomain.com, and I can add A records for one level below it, and my mail server obviously uses one of those subdomains for itself(mail.mydomain.com).  Do I have to set up a name server somewhere else to serve this lower level?